# Solving $x+y+z=4$, $x^2+y^2+z^2=14$, $x^3+y^3+z^3=34$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Solve the system $$\begin{equation} \label{equation1}
> \begin{split}
> x+y+z=4 \\
>      x^2+y^2+z^2=14 \\
> x^3+y^3+z^3=34
> \end{split}
> \end{equation}$$

My work:

I found out that $$xy+yz+xz=1$$ and $$x^2y+x^2z+y^2x+y^2z+z^2x+z^2y=22$$

After this I'm stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** This not a duplicate. I'm looking for a detailed solution and not a solution just by inspection. Also I thought of a new idea. Maybe e should consider a cubic polynomial whose roots are $x,y,z$

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2311771/746312

Comment: Or this one? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1359545/746312

Comment: @abcdefu FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D14%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x%5E3%2By%5E3%2Bz%5E2%3D34%24&p=1), your system of equations is asked about, but just the # of solutions (although the answer gives the actual values) in [Number of ordered triplet solutions $(x,y,z)$](/q/3488666). Also, the AoPS thread [System of Equations](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1676345p10679155) deals with this system of equations, with it giving more details on how to solve them. ...

Comment: A site search for ["x+y+z" "x^2+y^2+z^2" "x^3+y^3+z^3"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22x%2By%2Bz%22+%22x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%22+%22x%5E3%2By%5E3%2Bz%5E3%22) yields almost 400 results. Most are irrelevant, but the ones in the comments above, and at least a few more like them, appear.

Comment: @abcdefu (cont.) A couple of closely related questions are [Newton's sum help](/q/1240517) here, and the AoPS thread [simultaneous equations 2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1303458p6955053).

Comment: @Blue As my earlier comment indicated, the same system of equations was asked about at [Number of ordered triplet solutions $(x,y,z)$](/q/3488666). However, I didn't vote to close as a duplicate because that question just asked about how many solutions there were and, although the answer gives those solutions, it doesn't really provide any indication on how to determine the base one of $(3,2,-1)$ (with by inspection being the apparent implicit explanation). Do you think it's a duplicate?

Comment: @JohnOmielan no its not duplicate

Comment: @abcdefu: Please edit your question to explain why it's not a duplicate of [the one John linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3488666). (Eg, say that you're looking for a detailed solution, not simply the (evidently) by-inspection solution $(3,2,-1)$.) You could/should also say why the approaches shown in the answers linked in other comments are not as helpful as one might think. This will help people avoid giving similar advice.

Comment: Just use viete's relation as you already mentioned...otherwise resultant method is also a good way

Comment: @GooglePlayGames yeah...i did it by viete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is always the way of a direct computation. Substituting $z=4-x-y$, the other two equations are $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$, and the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $f$ and $g$ with respect to $y$ yields
$$
(x + 1)(x - 2)(x - 3)=0.
$$
So we have $x=-1$ or $x=2$ or $x=3$. To be more precise,
\begin{align}
f(x,y)& =x^2 + xy - 4x + y^2 - 4y + 1,\\
g(x,y)& = - x^2y + 4x^2 - xy^2 + 8xy - 16x + 4y^2 - 16y + 10.
\end{align}

Comment: This solution is good but actually I don't know about resultants yet

Comment: Therefore you have the wikipedia link, which is very nice to read with many examples.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

We observe that,

$$xy=\frac{(4-z)^2-(14-z^2)}{2}=f(z)$$

and

$$\begin{align}(4-z)(14-z^2)=xy(x+y)+x^3+y^3\\
=f(z)\times (4-z)+34-z^3\end{align}$$

After finding $z$, for the final step we need to solve

$$\begin{cases}x+y=4-z\\ xy =f(z)\end{cases}$$

By the [Vieta's formulas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we have

$$t^2-(4-z)t+f(z)=0$$

where, $$t_1=x,\, t_2=y \,\,\, \text{or}\,\,\,t_1=y,\, t_2=x $$

Thus for every $z$, we obtain the following solutions:

$$(z,x,y) \,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\, (z,y,x).$$

Answer (score 2):

$x+y+z=4$
$x^2+y^2+z^2=14$
$xy+yz+zx=1$(you already established)....(1)

$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz+3xyz=34$ 
$\Rightarrow (x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)+3xyz=34$ 
$\Rightarrow 4(14-1)+3xyz=34$
So, $xyz=-6$....(2)

From (1) and (2)
$(1/x)+(1/y)+(1/z)=-(1/6)$
$\Rightarrow (x+y)/xy+(1/z)=-(1/6)$
$\Rightarrow (4-z)/(-6/z)+(1/z)=-(1/6)$

Simplifying we get
$z^3-4z^2+z+6=0$
$\Rightarrow (z-3)(z-2)(z+1)=0$
$\therefore, z=3,2,-1$

Put these values in $x+y+z=4$ and $xyz=-6$, you can easily get the values of $x$ and $y$.

There will be 6 solutions, permutations of
$(3,2,-1)$.