# Solving the system $x+y+z=0$, $x^3+y^3+z^3=18$, $x^7+y^7+z^7=2058$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Solve the system
> $$\begin{equation} \label{equation1}
> \begin{split}
> x+y+z=0 \\
>      x^3+y^3+z^3=18 \\
> x^7+y^7+z^7=2058
> \end{split}
> \end{equation}$$

My work:

Let $$f(p)=p^3+ap^2+bp+c$$
having roots $x,y,z$

By viete's relations we can find that $x+y+z=-a$ or $z+x+y=0$
So our polynomial becomes $$f(p)=p^3+bp+c$$ Since $x,y,z$ are roots
$$\begin{equation} \label{equation2}
\begin{split}
x^3+bx+c=0 \\
     y^3+by+c=0 \\
z^3+bz+c=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$
Adding all equations $$x^3+y^3+z^3+b(x+y+z)+3c=0$$ or $$18+b\cdot0+3c=0$$ or $$c=-6$$ Our polynomial becomes $$f(p)=p^3+bp-6$$
After this I'm stuck. I can't find the value of $b$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4507702/357390)?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel that was my question

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I am not able to deal with power $7$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving $x+y+z=4$, $x^2+y^2+z^2=14$, $x^3+y^3+z^3=34$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507702/solving-xyz-4-x2y2z2-14-x3y3z3-34)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is always the way of a direct computation. It works the same way as here:

[Solving $x+y+z=4$, $x^2+y^2+z^2=14$, $x^3+y^3+z^3=34$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507702/solving-xyz-4-x2y2z2-14-x3y3z3-34)

Substituting $z=-x-y$, the other two equations are $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$, and the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $f$ and $g$ with respect to $y$ yields
$$
x(x^3+7x-6)(x+2)(x+1)(x-3)=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer but I think worth mentioning it.

Here is a solution based on linear recurrences.

If $x,y,z$ are different zeros of your polynomial
$f(p) = p^3 +bx -6$, then for natural $n\geq 0$

$$a_n = x^n+y^n+z^n$$

is the solution of the recurrence

$$a_{n+3} = -b\cdot a_{n+1} + 6a_n$$

with
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_0 & = & x^0+y^0+z^0 & = & 3 \\
a_1 & = & x^1+y^1+z^1 & = & 0 \\
a_3 & = & x^3+y^3+z^3 & = & 18 \\
\ldots
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, expanding $(x+y+z)^2$ you find $$-b=-(xy+yz+zx) = \frac 12a_2$$

Using this together with the recurrence you get:

\begin{eqnarray*}
a_4 & = &  \frac 12 a_2a_2 + 6a_1 & \stackrel{a_1=0}{=} &\frac 12 a_2^2\\
a_5 & = & \frac 12 a_2 a_3 + 6a_2 & = & 15a_2 \\
2058 & = & \frac 12 a_2 a_5 +6a_4& = & \frac{21}2 a_2^2 \\
\ldots
\end{eqnarray*}

It follows
$$a_2^2=196 \stackrel{a_2 > 0}{\Rightarrow} a_2 = 14 \Rightarrow b= -7$$

So, you get

$$f(p) = p^3-7p-6 \text{ with the easy to find zeros } -1,-2,3.$$